# How to use `clojure --main`

Tags: clojure

When reading `clojure -h`* I found the `--main` option:

```
  main options:
    -m, --main ns-name  Call the -main function from a namespace with args
```

Having the following code:

```clj
(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (println "Hello, World!"))
```

**Is it possible to utilize the `--main` argument to call directly the `-main` function without using `lein`?**

*`clojure` = `java ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar path_to_clojure.jar "$@"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Assuming -main function is in the file `./src/foo/core.clj` the following will run it:

`java -cp "path_to_clojure.jar:src" clojure.main --main foo.core` (note the `src` in the classpath)

Comment: So this will not work with `-jar` java option? foo.core is the namespace.filename ?

Comment: This won't work since you need to include code  with _your_ `-main` function to the classpath. But if your goal is to run your project without leiningen then you can generate executable jar with `lein uberjar` (it will contain your code and all dependencies including Clojure itself) and then you'll be able to run `java -jar <generated jar>`.